# Preserving Data Type At Exporting DataTable to Excel with Open Xml SDK in C#

Tags: c#, xml, excel, datarow

My code works fine except keeping numbers as numbers. If statement catches the double value when I debug. Yet I cannot write in a data type except string to Excel. If I should be more precise, the cells in Excel are correct but they are not numbers.

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
{
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
    foreach (String col in columns)
    {
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();

        if (dsrow[col].GetType() == typeof(Double))
        {
            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.Number;

        }
        else
        {
            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
        }

        cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //

        newRow.AppendChild(cell);
    }

    sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Office Open XMl SDK Writing Numbers to Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607063/office-open-xml-sdk-writing-numbers-to-sheet)

Comment: As can be seen in the answer of the question I just reported as duplicate in the case of numbers first put the value in and then change the data type. Else you are still making it an string, by the `ToString` method

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with the same problem.
It appears that the problem appears if you are using a locale with comma as decimal separator. In the XML it should be american format.

So specifying CutureInfo in ToString worked for me:

```
var dataRow = new Row();
var cell = new Cell();
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(1.234.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")));
cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
dataRow.AppendChild(cell);
sheetData.AppendChild(dataRow);
```